# Caratheodory derivative for a function $f: U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

In my complex analysis course I learned about the [Caratheodory Derivative](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CaratheodoryDerivative.html). I like this definition (or if we define differentiability else, the equivalence). So I wanted to adapt it to the real case. The following statement summarizes roughly my idea.

> Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and $f : U \to \mathbb{R}^m$. Then $f$ is differentiable in $a$ (in the ordinary sense) if and only if there exists a function $\varphi : U \to M_{mn}(\mathbb{R})$ continuous at $a$ such that $$f(x) = f(a) + \varphi(x)(x - a)$$
> holds for any $x \in U$.

So my questions are:

- Is this even a correct statement?
- Are there any references on this? I checked on the internet and in several books, but I was not lucky.
- How would one prove the above statement? A hint would be enough.

Sorry for this vague question, but I really did not find something usefull.

Comment: I believe Frechet differentiability and Caratheodory differentiability are almost the same notion. Anyways I've found this: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Cesar_Delgado2/publication/259998808_Acosta__Delgado_Frechet_vs_Carathodory/links/00b7d52efb3ec1f037000000.pdf